# PROGRESS 4GL Freezing

Tags: procedure, freeze, progress-4gl

I started new thread.
I have weird problem with program whose source i can not see.

I hook on entry events that program_b.p :

```
DEF VAR hField1 AS HANDLE.
DEF VAR hField2 AS HANDLE.
hField1 = getHandle( "field1", "frame1" ) . /* (This function is not important, works properly, returning handle to field in that frame) */
hField2 = getHandle( "field2", "frame1" ) .

/* Now i want to write something to field1 and go to field2 . */
IF FOCUS = field1 
THEN DO: 
    field1:screen-value = 'something'.
    APPLY "RETURN" TO field1. /* OR "ENTER" , doesn't matter because dont work */
    PAUSE 0 NO-MESSAGE.
END.

PAUSE 0. /* Just in case  */
```

And when in original program I entry on the field1 this program_b is executed.
But after updating field1 its freezing and waiting for any key. (its not "Press space bar to continue" ) . After 'anykey' its enter field2. In field2 i have no such problem. Its automatic goes to field3. And on field3 the same problem. Other fields ( i have 7 ) are working properly. Only field1 and field3 is causing this freeze.

Answer (score 0):

You are only showing small snippets and not enough code to really say what is going on but:

```
RETURN NO-APPLY.
```

Is chicken soup for triggers.  Especially triggers that modify field contents within the UI. You might just try adding that to whatever it is that you are doing.